# PSE Advent Calendar 2021 (Day 3): Tentai Show

Tags: grid-deduction, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling StackExchange Advent Calendar 2021](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112869/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-2-a-christmas-tree-for-broke-nerds) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112909)</sub>

---

[image: empty Tentai Show grid]

Divide the grid into "rooms" along grid lines so that each room is 180° rotationally symmetrical and contains exactly one white or black circle, located in its centre. In the end, shade all rooms with a black circle in them to form a picture.

<sub>Paraphrased from original rules on [Nikoli](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/astronomical_show.html)</sub>

Comment: For interested solvers, a [puzz.link](https://puzz.link/p?tentaisho/15/16/eaezu2827ekewepfezzr55ei9epepeyfoen6fkezzxehekeh338cfzm8ezxfn27eia7eyezwfm9emeqcfznceieemezjdfzqek8ene). No warranty expressed or implied, but I think I got it right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry for the formatting; I can try to clean it up and provide steps with a bit more time if desired.

> [image: full puzzle solved]

At the very least, I'll point out the main "hurdle" point I faced.  After initial markings, focus on the marked cell:

> [image]

> The wall blocks most points from being centers for regions containing the starred cell.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the problem using the [UI which Jeremy Dover linked to in the comments](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112877/pse-advent-calendar-2021-day-3-tentai-show#comment318573_112877).

In my case, the main hurdle was when I got to this point:

> [image: Main hurdle]

I kept on staring at the cell highlighted in yellow, and I could not figure out a way to make a symmetrical room that includes it and has a star in the center.

Eventually, I realized that the only possibility is a shape that reaches all the way to the top of the grid.

After I filled that in, everything else eventually fell into place.

This is what the solved puzzle looks like:

> [image: Solved puzzle]